# Twitter Bootstrap Website Deployed with GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, twitter-bootstrap, blogs

So I'm a programming noob. I have been following many of the Udacity classes and I am slowly learning to code.

Alright so here's my question. I have built the basic HTML files of my blog using Twitter Bootstrap as it is so simple to use. Now what I would like to do is to combine the great template's that Bootstrap provides with the simple hosting services of Google App Engine. This is where my noobness comes in and I'm totally lost.

Any help would be appreciated, don't be afraid to hurt my feelings I am noob and will understand if this is completely impossible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at gae-boilerplate.  Its based on webapp2 and twitter bootstrap.

- Docs https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate
- demo http://appengine.beecoss.com/

It does pretty much what you want out of the box along with a bunch of other features you may well want.

Comment: Hey Tim thanks for the info I'm having a hard time setting up boilerplate and can't seem to find a good tutorial online. Even after reading the docs i still get this error saying its not configured properly

Comment: any specific error.  I installed it under ubuntu about 2 weeks ago with no problems.  What OS, python etc.....

Comment: @user1541473 You can try gae-init.appspot.com :) Simply clone it and run the dev_appserver.py for the main folder

Answer (score 19):

It is perfectly possible. Download bootstrap to a separate folder and in your app.yaml file, have your handler which is a `static_dir` for /bootstrap

```
application: application-name
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /bootstrap
  static_dir: bootstrap

- url: /.*
  script: todoapp.py
```

And in all your html files refere to bootstrap like this.

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

You should be good to go!

Comment: Thank you so much for the info, gonna try this out in the morning but one question before i go, at the end you wrote 'todoapp.py'? I am a little confused as the what that is.

Comment: Yes, that's just my code. you may replace it with your application which has the main

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answers above, also note that the order of declarations is important. The  - url: /.* part should be the last one, in this case

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved me some time! Upvote for you. Normally it should be a comment though.

Comment: you saved my day

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the addition above, for all of the sub-domains you should write another static directory. So that, (e.g) if you have your new post form for blog at /blog/newpost, you should add

```
-url: /blog/bootstrap
 static_dir: bootstrap
```

Missing this point,I have spent much time, figuring out why bootstrap didn't work at sub-domains. Keep in my writing this piece of code before -url:/.* declaration.