# GAE can't access bootstrap folder

Tags: google-app-engine, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a noob missing something very rudimentary.  Taking the advice of Senthil Kumaran [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681557/twitter-bootstrap-website-deployed-with-gae/11681624#11681624), I added the bootstrap folder to my app.yaml, but I still can't reference the resources.  My app.yaml looks like:

```
application: generacy
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /.*
  script: blog.app

- url: /bootstrap
  static_dir: bootstrap

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest

- name: PIL
  version: "1.1.7"
```

and I'm referring to bootstrap js using this at the bottom:

```
<script src="bootstrap/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/assests/js/holder.js"></script>
```

but it doesn't work.  However, if I put the files in my static folder, and refer to them as:

```
<script src="static/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="static/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/holder.js"></script>
```

It does work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your static handler before the wildcard .* handler.  Its getting all requests.

This is a duplicate of a lot of questions.

Comment: Lets find the duplicate and close this one then...